# Is it possible to use Compress-Archive using a PSDrive in the -Path and -DestinationPath?

Tags: powershell, compress-archive, new-psdrive

I am using a PSDrive for Compress-Archive but I come across this error:

```
Compress-Archive : The path 'Z:\' either does not exist or is not a valid file system path.
At C:\Users\user\somefolder\script.ps1:34 char:5
+     Compress-Archive -Path ($ZDrive + $fileName + $csvExt) -Destinati ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Z:\:String) [Compress-Archive], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArchiveCmdletPathNotFound,Compress-Archive
```

The PSDrive code and codes at line 33 and 34 are these:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "Z" -Root $OutputDirectoryPath -PSProvider FileSystem;
$ZDrive = "Z:\";
```

```
query($CustomQuery) | Export-Csv -Path ($ZDrive + $fileName + $csvExt) -NoTypeInformation;
Compress-Archive -Path ($ZDrive + $fileName + $csvExt) -DestinationPath ($ZDrive + $fileName + $zipExt) -Force;
```

Comment: As per the error, it is not able to pick the Z drive whatever you have created in PSDrive. 
Compress-Archive do not support paths containing PSDrives .

Why not just compress in a local drive first, then create the PSdrive and just move it inside the drive. That makes the operation much more simpler

Comment: Makes sense. I'll go do that, thanks! I'll leave this question open, just in case there are future developments to PS or if anybody else has a solution.

Comment: I will put the comment as an answer so that you can at least mark it as a solution.